# How to display distinct json genre names (and total number of each genre type)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, distinct

I have JSON data structured like so...

```
{
    "resp": [{
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "3.5",
        "name": "Passion",
        "vid": 12345,

    }, {
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "1.9",
        "name": "Galaxy",
        "vid": 12346,


    }, {
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "1.4",
        "name": "Sun",
        "vid": 12347,


    }, {
        "genreID": 8,
        "genre": "Thriller",
        "length": "15.1",
        "name": "Moonlight ",
        "vid": 12348,


    }, {
        "genreID": 8,
        "genre": "Thriller",
        "length": "10.6",
        "name": "Sunlight",
        "vid": 12349,


    }]
}
```

I would like to create following hyperlinks from above json data and once we click on each genre name hyperlink it should only display data from that genre only. Right now my code display the whole json in a list using the code below.

Want to create following hyperlinks:

```
All TV Series(3)
Thriller(2)
```

How would I accomplish this with Javascript/jQuery? Unfortunately I can't edit what the server is sending me.

code:

```
success: function(data) {

   self.itemParts = data.resp;

    for (var i = 0; i < self.itemParts.length; i++) 
    {


       // create HTML code
       var div = "<div class=\"image\">\n" + 
       "<a href=\"javascript:loadList('" + self.itemParts[i].vid+ "')\">\n" +
       "<img src=\"http://somesite.com/images/l"+ self.itemParts[i].vid +".png\" alt=\"..\" />"+ self.itemParts[i].name+"\n" +
       "</a>\n" +
       "</div>\n";
       // append it inside <body> tag.
       $("#myDiv").append(div);

    }


<div id='myDiv' style="display: visiable;">  

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the returned data resides in a variable called `data`

```
let data = {
    "resp": [{
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "3.5",
        "name": "Passion",
        "vid": 12345,

    }, {
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "1.9",
        "name": "Galaxy",
        "vid": 12346,


    }, {
        "genreID": 1,
        "genre": "All TV Series",
        "length": "1.4",
        "name": "Sun",
        "vid": 12347,


    }, {
        "genreID": 8,
        "genre": "Thriller",
        "length": "15.1",
        "name": "Moonlight ",
        "vid": 12348,


    }, {
        "genreID": 8,
        "genre": "Thriller",
        "length": "10.6",
        "name": "Sunlight",
        "vid": 12349,


    }]
};

let model = {};
let values = data.resp;
values.forEach(function(value) {
  //creating separate groups for each type
  model[value.genre] = model[value.genre] || [];
  model[value.genre].push(value);
});
```

then do another iteration to generate the links:

### es6

```
for(let genre in model) {
  $("#myDiv").append(`<a href="#">${genre}(${model[genre].length})</a>`); 
}
```

### es5

```
for(let genre in model) {
  $("#myDiv").append('<a href="#">'+genre+'('+model[genre].length+')</a>'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replies. I tried to use your code inside ajax but i keep getting error missing ; before let data2=data.resp ! How to fix it ?

Comment: i still get this ==>error missing ; before statement

let model = {};

Comment: It's fairly odd, as it shouldn't error. I've made a small edit, please check again @user1788736

Comment: i used var instead of let but now it prints  ${genre}(${model[genre].length} instead of genre names using this  line $("#myDiv").append("<a href=\"#\">${genre}(${model[genre].length})</a>");

Comment: Because this is not the code I posted. Please use it as is.
I will add an edit for more common browser cases

Comment: I used es5 code the names of genres are correct but the values inside ( )are not correct. I want the total number of each genre name not value of length

Comment: I've updated the code so that you can enjoy both, you'll have the correct output now.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me it printed the genre name and total number. Now if i want to display only a specific genre data how can i filter that data from json by clicking the genre names that we just printed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136977/discussion-between-silicakes-and-user1788736).

Comment: since it strays from the original question - I've moved us to a separate chat. please approve the answer, if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
var obj = {
  "resp": [{
    "genreID": 1,
    "genre": "All TV Series",
    "length": "3.5",
    "name": "Passion",
    "vid": 12345,

  }, {
    "genreID": 1,
    "genre": "All TV Series",
    "length": "1.9",
    "name": "Galaxy",
    "vid": 12346,


  }, {
    "genreID": 1,
    "genre": "All TV Series",
    "length": "1.4",
    "name": "Sun",
    "vid": 12347,


  }, {
    "genreID": 8,
    "genre": "Thriller",
    "length": "15.1",
    "name": "Moonlight ",
    "vid": 12348,


  }, {
    "genreID": 8,
    "genre": "Thriller",
    "length": "10.6",
    "name": "Sunlight",
    "vid": 12349,


  }]
};

var response = {};

obj.resp.forEach(function(item) {
  response[item.genre] = response[item.genre] || 0;
  response[item.genre]++;
});


console.log(response);
```

Now you can iterate over the response and paint.

Comment: How to print these values as hyperlink titles?